# German or other languages possible with the Botframework?

Tags: azure, botframework

Is there a possiblity to use another language (e.g. German) for the botframework? Language Recognition, Language Understanding etc.? If not any plans to introduce other languages? Thanks

Comment: Try to use Bing Translator API for converting the utterance from German to English

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Bot Framework itself is not specific to a language, it's the tools that you can combine that may be limited.

For example:

- [Webchat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/) channel: ok for german, just need to set the locale (with the URL or in locale parameter)
- LUIS (Language Understanding): ok for [german](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-supported-languages?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)
- Bing SpellCheck : ok for [german](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-spell-check-api-v7-reference?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#market-codes)

Comment: If that reply was helpful, please don't forget to accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only related 'gotcha' I know of is Q & A Maker, each KB needs to be in the target language. I.e. if you create a brand new KB and upload a document in French then that KB will now be in French. It's because the underlying Azure Search will be set to the first document's language.